# Split String separated by emojis

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, swift, swift3

I would split a String in an array of emoji and sentence in the correct order.

**UPDATE**

Fell free to use other functions, I've tried "split" but is not mandatory.

**FINISH UPDATE**

> Example: "‍‍‍ pippo sta pippando "  -->  ["‍‍‍",
>   "pippo sta pippando", ""]

**What I have already tried:**

```
let str = "‍‍‍ pippo sta pippando "
print(Array(str))
```

> //["‍‍‍", " ", "p", "i", "p", "p", "o", " ", "s", "t", "a",
>   "", "p", "i", "p", "p", "a", "n", "d", "o", " ", ""]

```
let arrTot = str.split(whereSeparator: { $0 == " "})
print(arrTot)
```

> //["‍‍‍", "pippo", "sta", "pippando", ""]

```
for p in arrTot {
    print(String(p).containsEmoji)
}
```

> /*true
>        false
>        false
>        false
>        true
>        */
>   so the containsEmoji is working

but when I want use split:

```
print(str.split(whereSeparator: {$0.containsEmoji }))
```

> //[" pippo sta pippando "]

is filtering instead split

> what I want->My wished output: ["‍‍‍", "pippo sta pippando", ""]

Any idea?

**EXTENSION:**

```
extension UnicodeScalar {
    var isEmoji: Bool {

        switch value {
        case 0x1F600...0x1F64F, // Emoticons
        0x1F300...0x1F5FF, // Misc Symbols and Pictographs
        0x1F680...0x1F6FF, // Transport and Map
        0x2600...0x26FF,   // Misc symbols
        0x2700...0x27BF,   // Dingbats
        0xFE00...0xFE0F,   // Variation Selectors
        0x1F900...0x1F9FF,  // Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs
        65024...65039, // Variation selector
        8400...8447: // Combining Diacritical Marks for Symbols
            return true

        default: return false
        }
    }

    var isZeroWidthJoiner: Bool {
        return value == 8205
    }
}
extension String {
    var containsEmoji: Bool {
        return unicodeScalars.contains { $0.isEmoji }
    }
}
extension Character {
    var containsEmoji: Bool {
        return unicodeScalars.contains { $0.isEmoji }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the Emojis alway separated by spaces from the remaining text? Can there be a sequence of two (or more) Emojis without other characters between them? If yes, what would be the expected result, e.g. for `"foobar"` ?

Comment: Nope, the text in input is free by the user, so I must foresee all the cases, close the text, with one space, two or tree space etc

Comment: @alessandro-ornano any suggestion? :)